# No wiring beans when using Grails Rendering Plugin

Tags: spring, grails

When I add Grails Rendering Plugin (`compile "org.grails.plugins:rendering:2.0.1"`) into my dependencies all my SpockUnit test with controllers are getting broken.

The error that I got is:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [grails.plugins.rendering.image.PngRenderingService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1301)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1047)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:942)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:533)
    ... 38 more
```

Also I have in my build.gradle file dependency on Spring test: `runtime 'org.springframework:spring-test:4.1.7.RELEASE'`. As far as I know this is needed for rendering plugin

Grails version: **3.0.9**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed in this issue https://github.com/gpc/rendering/issues/31

Will be merged in version above 2.0.1